# js 'address' variable in Checkout

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, javascript

Can somebody explain where does 'address' variable come from in i.e file

> app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-information

'address' is used many times as argument into functions i.e

> createRendererComponent: function (address)

But I cant see declaration of this variable. Why it is accessible from this context?